# How to get the sidebar to not interact?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a webpage that adds points when you click on it. There is a sidebar(just a left column) where there are images that act as checkboxes. Selecting one image gets you 1 point when you click on the page, selecting the other gives 5...
However, I don't want to have the sidebar give points. It means that when you click on it, it only changes the selected image, without adding points. Everything is working except the "not adding points on the sidebar" part. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```js
function addPoint(number) {
  points = points + number;
  document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = points;
};

function pointsAmount() {
  chkBox1 = document.getElementById('picture1').checked;
  addPoint(chkBox1 ? 1 : 0);
  chkBox2 = document.getElementById('picture2').checked;
  addPoint(chkBox2 ? 5 : 0);
  chkBox3 = document.getElementById('picture3').checked;
  addPoint(chkBox3 ? 10 : 0);
  chkBox4 = document.getElementById('picture4').checked;
  addPoint(chkBox4 ? 20 : 0);
};

function checkPicture(x, y) {
  document.getElementById(x).checked = y;
}

function Border(x, y) {
  document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor = y;
}

function onPageload() {
  checkPicture('picture1', true);
  Border('pic1', 'yellow');
}
window.onload = onPageload;
window.onmousedown = function(e) {
  if (e.target.className != 'float-left-area') {
    pointsAmount();
  }
}
var points = 0;
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=button] {
  display: none;
}

.float-left-area {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 99%;
}

.float-right-area {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-left {
  font-size: 2em;
}

img.size {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left-area">
  <div class="inner-left">
    <label for="picture1"><div id="pic1" style="border: 5px solid black;"><img src="eslcc_logo2.png" alt="eslcc logo" style="float:left;" class="size" /><p align="right">1</p></div></label>
    <input id="picture1" type="checkbox" onchange="checkPicture('picture1', true)" onclick="
checkPicture('picture2', false);
checkPicture('picture3', false);
checkPicture('picture4', false); 
Border('pic1', 'yellow');
Border('pic2', 'black');
Border('pic3', 'black');
Border('pic4', 'black');" />
    <label for="picture2"><div id="pic2" style="border: 5px solid black;"><img src="imac_2.jpg" style="float:left;" class="size" alt="iMac" /><p align="right">5</p></div></label>
    <input id="picture2" type="checkbox" onchange="checkPicture('picture2', true)" onclick="
checkPicture('picture1', false);
checkPicture('picture3', false);
checkPicture('picture4', false); 
Border('pic2', 'yellow');
Border('pic1', 'black');
Border('pic3', 'black');
Border('pic4', 'black');" />
    <label for="picture3"><div id="pic3" style="border: 5px solid black;"><img src="coding_img.png" style="float:left;" class="size" alt="iMac" /><p align="right">10</p></div></label>
    <input id="picture3" type="checkbox" onchange="checkPicture('picture3', true)" onclick="
checkPicture('picture1', false);
checkPicture('picture2', false);
checkPicture('picture4', false); 
Border('pic3', 'yellow');
Border('pic1', 'black');
Border('pic2', 'black');
Border('pic4', 'black');" />
    <label for="picture4"><div id="pic4" style="border: 5px solid black;"><img src="ariane_6.jpg" style="float:left;" class="size" alt="Ariane 6"/><p align="right">20</p></div></label>
    <input id="picture4" type="checkbox" onchange="checkPicture('picture4', true)" onclick="
checkPicture('picture1', false);
checkPicture('picture2', false);
checkPicture('picture3', false); 
Border('pic4', 'yellow');
Border('pic1', 'black');
Border('pic2', 'black');
Border('pic3', 'black');" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="float-right-area">
  <div class="inner-right">
    <p align="center">Points: <span id="points">0</span></p>
```

Also, no jQuery please.

Comment: Please try to make our job at helping you easier by providing a [mcve] of your problem (create a snippet using the `<>` button, instead of providing each part separately - and make sure it all works here, in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

I remove the bulky code in the checkbox input and set different values in the attribute (i.e. `value`, `data-pic`), then consolidate all actions in the `function addPoint(number)`.

I have also modified `function pointsAmount()` by using `for` loop to get the points of selected picture. And points will only be added when you click on the right side area.

```js
function addPoint(number) {
    points = points + number;
    document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = points;
}

function checkPicture(x, y) {
    document.getElementById(x).checked = y;
}

function Border(x, y) {
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor = y;
}

function selectPicture(selectedPic) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('picture');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
    {
        var id = checkboxes[i].id;
        var pic = checkboxes[i].getAttribute('data-pic');

        // Default state and style
        checkPicture(id, false);
        Border(pic, 'black');

        if (id == selectedPic.id)
        {                   
            checkPicture(id, true);
            Border(pic, 'yellow');
        }
    }
}

function pointsAmount() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('picture');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
    {                   
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
        {                       
            var value = parseInt(checkboxes[i].value);
            addPoint(value);
        }
    }
}

function onPageload() {
    checkPicture('picture1', true);
    Border('pic1', 'yellow');
}
window.onload = onPageload;

window.onmousedown = function(e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'float-right-area') {
        pointsAmount();
    }
}

var points = 0;
```

```html
<div class="float-left-area">
    <div class="inner-left">
        <label for="picture1">
            <div id="pic1" style="border: 5px solid black;">
                <img src="eslcc_logo2.png" alt="eslcc logo" style="float:left;" class="size">
                <p align="right">1</p>
            </div>
        </label>
        <input id="picture1" type="checkbox" name="picture" data-pic="pic1" value="1" onclick="selectPicture(this)">

        <label for="picture2">
            <div id="pic2" style="border: 5px solid black;">
                <img src="imac_2.jpg" style="float:left;" class="size" alt="iMac">
                <p align="right">5</p>
            </div>
        </label>
        <input id="picture2" type="checkbox" name="picture" data-pic="pic2" value="5" onclick="selectPicture(this)">

        <label for="picture3">
            <div id="pic3" style="border: 5px solid black;">
                <img src="coding_img.png" style="float:left;" class="size" alt="iMac">
                <p align="right">10</p>
            </div>
        </label>
        <input id="picture3" type="checkbox" name="picture" data-pic="pic3" value="10" onclick="selectPicture(this)">

        <label for="picture4">
            <div id="pic4" style="border: 5px solid black;">
                <img src="ariane_6.jpg" style="float:left;" class="size" alt="Ariane 6">
                <p align="right">20</p>
            </div>
        </label>
        <input id="picture4" type="checkbox" name="picture" data-pic="pic4" value="20" onclick="selectPicture(this)">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="float-right-area">
    <div class="inner-right">
        <p align="center">Points: <span id="points">0</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```